# Grails test-app -https

Tags: grails, testing, cucumber, geb

i've just upgraded my app to grails 2.3.4 and i'm implementing Cucumber and Geb test in order to keep it all covered.

The problem is that one of the requirements of the application that should only listen secure connections (https) so i added in config groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.forceHttps = "true"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
    '/**':'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL'
]
```

Now, the problem is when i run grails test-app -https, is not working the param -https and only starts the application in non-secure channel.

Any ideas to run test-app in https?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using `-httpBaseUrl` with `-https` as well?

Comment: Yes, I've used both but the older versions of grails didn't need to use httpBaseUrl.
I think is a 2.3.4 problem

Any other ideas?

Comment: I have the same issue as well. Upon digging into the source code of Grails (2.3.7), found that this is because [`FunctionalTestPhaseConfigurer.prepare`](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-test/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/test/runner/phase/FunctionalTestPhaseConfigurer.groovy?source=c#L60-L149) completely disregards the `testOptions` containing the `-https` switch.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a Grails bug. I have submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/pull/479) and also added a comment to this question.